# How can I know what the columns are of a sql script like select * from xxxx?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, select

For example I get a custom report then the user can write any sql script.

In this case is `Select * FROM table_x`.

How can I know what're the columns of this script are?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM   information_schema.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='xxxx'`

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried about this at the procedural level, your ORM will probably tell you when you pull them down. If you're using classic ADO.net, you can look at the resultant (probably) `DataTable`'s columns.

If you're worried about this at the SQL Server level, you'd have to figure out the name of the table (for instance, by finding the next word after `FROM`, but that's pretty sketchy in my opinion), then you can do:

```
SELECT *
FROM Information_Schema.Columns
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'ThatTableName'
```

That'll tell you a bit about them, including their `COLUMN_NAME`.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2012 and later, you can use `sp_describe_first_result_set`:

```
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set @tsql = N'SELECT * FROM table_x;';
```

Comment: Thanks for All I got the solution with reader.getName[index] this statement give me the name of the column of this item reader.